# Parse Json_encoded array from PHP in C# UWP

Tags: c#, php, json, uwp

I developing a UWP app using C#, this conect a PHP WebService, this web service return a array encoded using json_encode function, i cant parse this json string in my UWP app, please help

1: PHP CODE

```
$aCli[]=  array("CAT"=>"OK","MSG"=>"SESION-OK","EXTRA"=>array("ID"=>"$spID","NOM"=>"$spNom"));
echo json_encode($aCli);
```

2: The result using postman is:

```
[{"CAT":"OK","MSG":"SESION-OK","EXTRA":{"ID":"3","NOM":"CHARLS"}}]
```

3. The result using Async Task from C# is:

```
"[{\"CAT\":\"OK\",\"MSG\":\"SESION-OK\",\"EXTRA\":{\"ID\":\"3\",\"NOM\":\"CHARLS\"}}]"
```

4. How to deserialize this string?, i am trying it using

```
using Windows.Data.Json;
```

5. This is the code using in this time

```
sJSON= await IniciarSesion();//this use async class to connect with webservice
JsonObject objJson = JsonObject.Parse(sJSON);//error is raised in this line
/*Json String is invalid*/
sCat = objJson["CAT"].GetString();
sMsg = objJson["MSG"].GetString();
```

Comment: Show IniciarSesion code.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but your JSON is a representation of an array, not an object.  Could you use JsonArray instead of JsonObject, perhaps (or, change your php to just return the object)

Comment: as per @James, replace `$aCli[] = blabla` to `$aCli = blabla` (the json encoded object) , not a json encoded array of one object.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg i need encode array,  for list records from table from other page un my app

Answer (score 0):

Important comment above:

> your JSON is a representation of an array, not an object.

**IF** you can use [Newtonsoft (JSON.Net)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), here's [one way, with dependency on `JSON.Net`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dE05qa), not `Windows.Data.Json`. Trivial sample only, improve as necessary (null checks, etc.)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "[{\"CAT\":\"OK\",\"MSG\":\"SESION-OK\",\"EXTRA\":{\"ID\":\"3\",\"NOM\":\"CHARLS\"}}]";
        var j = JArray.Parse(str);
        var token = j[0];

        //using dynamic to simplify sample, create/use your own type
        var obj = token.ToObject<dynamic>(); 

        Console.WriteLine(obj.CAT);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.MSG);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.EXTRA);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.EXTRA.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.EXTRA.NOM);
    }
}
```

Hth..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize JSON string directly. For your requirement, you need to make the data model fist.

> [{"CAT":"OK","MSG":"SESION-OK","EXTRA":{"ID":"3","NOM":"CHARLS"}}]

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Cat { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public Extra Extra { get; set; }
}

public class Extra
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var str = "[{\"CAT\":\"OK\",\"MSG\":\"SESION-OK\",\"EXTRA\":{\"ID\":\"3\",\"NOM\":\"CHARLS\"}}]";
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Pet>>(str);
}
```

For more you could refer [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the brackets ' [] ' at the beginning and end of the string,

You should trim them like:

' YOUR_JSON_STRING = YOUR_JSON_STRING.trim('[',']');

and then parse the json string below:

' dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING)'